# Getting NaN Error While Using LSTM Autoencoder

Tags: python, keras, lstm, nan, autoencoder

I am trying to train a model with LSTM Autoencoder using Keras to reconstruct the input that I gave to the model and I am getting NaN error in result which I obtain after decode part. Here is my code;

```py
    # lstm autoencoder recreate sequence
    from numpy import array
    import numpy as np
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import LSTM
    from keras.layers import Dense
    from keras.layers import RepeatVector
    from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
    from keras.utils import plot_model
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_csv('flight_data.csv',sep=',',header=None)
    data = df.to_numpy()
    print(data.shape)


    # define input sequence
    sequence1 = array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9])
    sequence2 = array([0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.4, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8])
    # reshape input into [samples, timesteps, features]
    n_in = 100
    data = data[73666:,:]
    sequence = data.reshape((1,100,24))
    print(sequence)
    # define model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_in,24)))
    model.add(RepeatVector(n_in))
    model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(24)))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
    # fit model
    model.fit(sequence, sequence, epochs=300, verbose=0)
    plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, to_file='reconstruct_lstm_autoencoder.png')
    # demonstrate recreation
    yhat = model.predict(sequence, verbose=0)

    print(yhat)
```

I got the output as;

```
[[[9.46687355e+14 1.00000000e+01 4.42748822e+08 ... 0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
  [9.46687355e+14 1.00000000e+01 4.42748822e+08 ... 0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
  [9.46687355e+14 1.00000000e+01 4.42748823e+08 ... 0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
  ...
  [9.46687359e+14 1.00000000e+01 4.42748824e+08 ... 0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
  [9.46687359e+14 1.00000000e+01 4.42748824e+08 ... 0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
  [9.46687359e+14 1.00000000e+01 4.42748825e+08 ... 0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]]]

[[[nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]
  [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]
  [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]
  ...
  [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]
  [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]
  [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]]]
```

Which part might causing a problem? What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you have exploding gradients, which LSTM have a tendency to create. Clipping the gradients can solve this, try setting clipnorm to 1.

```
ADAM = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False, clipnorm=1.)
model.compile(optimizer=ADAM, loss='mse')
```

Comment: Thanks. After that, I got;

    [[[ 7.80484634e+12  9.02850780e+13 -6.35291671e+12 ...  3.75248482e+13
    9.01600772e+12 -2.42150550e+13]
  ...
  [-3.17999043e+14  1.97286219e+14 -6.12970351e+14 ...  3.82576896e+14
    1.33085736e+14 -4.91843985e+14]]]

It seems like values are irrelevant. Why do you think this is happening? Can it be because of the parameters?

Comment: It removed the NaNs? Hmm, i think it has more to do with your actual data. How much data do you have and how does it look?

Comment: Actually, I have data with more than 70000 row with 24 features in a csv file but I am using 100 of them. However, when I decided to make it 10000, output becomes NaN again.

Comment: Hmm, maybe try set clipvalue=0.5 in the optimiser. Your 24 features, how do they look? Do they vary a lot in ranges?